# Match all digits but splitted in single characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is my string:

> Hello world, '4567' is my number.

If `/g` (global modifier) was supported in .NET, There was no problem to get what I want, but now, I don't know what to do and need your help. I need match all digits (`4567`) but splitted in single characters. I want it like this:

> match 1: 4,
>   match 2: 5,
>   match 3: 6,
>   match 4: 7

Thanks,
Alireza

Comment: Try the [`Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) method to get more than one match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all the matches i.e. digits in your case.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("Hello world, '4567' is my number.", "\\d"); 
    foreach(Match match in matches)
       Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Adil. I was thinking `Regex.Matches()` method does not support something I want.

Answer (score 2):

### **Without , separation:**

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("Hello world, '4567' is my number 679.", "\\d");
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Match {0}: {1}", i + 1, matches[i].ToString()));
```

It also works if you have more than once numbers in your string.

**Output:**

> Match 1: 4
>
> Match 2: 5
>
> Match 3: 6
>
> Match 4: 7
>
> Match 5: 6
>
> Match 6: 7
>
> Match 7: 9

### **With , separation:**

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, "\\d");
string result = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    result += string.Format("Match {0}: {1}", i + 1, matches[i].ToString() + ", ");

Console.WriteLine(result.Trim().Trim(','));
```

**Output:**

> Match 1: 4, Match 2: 5, Match 3: 6, Match 4: 7, Match 5: 6, Match 6: 7, Match 7: 9

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has been tagged with Regex, but here is another option **without REGEX**

```
foreach (var item in "Hello world, '4567' is my number.".Where(char.IsDigit))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Habib. Using Regex has better performance and readability in my situation. I gave your post +1 because It teaches something good.

Comment: @Alireza, readability umm not really sure, I am no expert at REGEX and find it hard to read, Performance, I believe this solution would out perform the one with Regex. You may see: http://ideone.com/ObBV7l , try increasing the iteration to 10 Million, *I can't do that on ideone because of time limit* , and see the difference between execution time.

Comment: May be compiled Regex would perform differently, but again I am not sure about it.

Comment: Yes @Habib, You are right. The performance of your code is better, but believe me `[0-9]` has more readability and everybody knows that means digits, but your code needs more reading code ability to understand. If the input string supposed to be less than 8000 lines (almost equals to 43,827 bytes) * 10, I would rather your code. Know that I learned two things, thanks to You.